# How to show customers list as a pop up window in Odoo PoS screen?

Tags: jquery, odoo, point-of-sale, pos, odoo-13

I am trying to show the customers list in PoS as a pop-up window. I have added necessary styles to the `clientlist-screen` screen div for this purpose. But the problem I am facing is the `product-screen` div is hidden in the background. Odoo has added a class named `oe_hidden` to it which prevents it from showing in the background. I have tried the following to show the `product-screen` div in the click function of the Customer button widget(`ActionpadWidget`), but none of them is working.

```
self.gui.show_screen('products');
$(".my-products-div").show(); // added new class to products div and tried show() method
$(".product-screen  ").removeClass("oe_hidden");
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Search "this.gui.show_popup " in addons/point_of_sale
it will be like this :

```
self.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                'title': _t('Delete Paid Orders ?'),
                'body':  _t('This operation will permanently destroy all paid orders from the local storage. You will lose all the data. This operation cannot be undone.'),
                confirm: function(){
                    self.pos.db.remove_all_orders();
                    self.pos.set({synch: { state:'connected', pending: 0 }});
                },
            });
```

use this function ! edit it according to you requirement,although u can create similar widget. but why ? when u can reuse POS- builtin widget instead.